# How to round a datetime to the nearest 200th millisecond?

Tags: c#, .net

In a C#.Net app I am writing, I am looking to round some DateTime values to the nearest 200th millisecond. I have come up with the following code;

```
   public static DateTime RoundToTheTwoHundredthMillisecond(DateTime dt) {            
        var ms = dt.Millisecond;
        var s = dt.Second;
        var m = dt.Minute;
        var h = dt.Hour;
        var d = dt.Day;
        var M = dt.Month;
        var y = dt.Year;
        if (ms >= 900 && ms < 1000) ms = 1000; 
        if (ms >= 700 && ms < 900) ms = 800;
        if (ms >= 500 && ms < 700) ms = 600;
        if (ms >= 300 && ms < 500) ms = 400;
        if (ms >= 100 && ms < 300) ms = 200;
        if (ms >= 0 && ms < 100) ms = 0;

        // 1000 is an invalid millisecond. We need to round up a second. Use AddSeconds so it will automatically roll up should we be 1 second away from a new minute, 1 minute away from a new hour...etc...leap years and months are handled also....
        if (ms == 1000) {                
            return new DateTime(y, M, d, m, h, s, 0, dt.Kind).AddSeconds(1);
        } 
        else {
            return new DateTime(y, M, d, m, h, s, ms, dt.Kind);
        }                     
    }
```

I *think* it is probably working. But I was wondering if anyone could point me to a method that might be more reliable than my fumblings? Alternately, perhaps, is this something that one would/should write a unit test for? (Doing that also seems prone to my own fumblings)

Comment: It should be sufficient to divide `ms` by `200`, then round, then multiply by 200, e.g. `Math.Round(ms/200)*200`.

Comment: I'm not a `.net` user, but assuming a DateTime object has the method `AddMilliseconds`,
Can't you just do:
`return dt.AddMilliseconds(200 - dt.ms % 200)`
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just divide with 200, round and multiply back to get the value. Also you can just subtract the difference from the original `DateTime`, no need to rebuild it  component my component.

```
public static DateTime RoundToTheTwoHundredthMillisecond(DateTime dt)
{
    var ms = Math.Round(dt.Millisecond / 200.0) * 200;
    return dt.AddMilliseconds(ms- dt.Millisecond);
}
```

**Edit**

To mimic the exact `if` sequence we can use `MidpointRounding`

```
public static DateTime RoundToTheTwoHundredthMillisecond(DateTime dt)
{
    var ms = Math.Round(dt.Millisecond / 200.0, MidpointRounding.ToEven) * 200;
    return dt.AddMilliseconds(ms- dt.Millisecond);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` to match OPs expectations.

Comment: @Evk hm, you are right, it's not just straight up rounding to the nearest `200`, I'' try to replicate the behavior, and edit in a second

Comment: Here is a link to MidpointRounding (For those who dont know what it is. i.e. me) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression (has mistake)

```
var value = DateTime.Now;
var roundedValue = DateTime.MinValue + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(((((long)((value - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds) + 199) / 200) * 200)));
```

UPDATE:
correct code with less amount of brackets ;)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 20; ++index)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(349);
            DateTime value = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime rounded = value.RoundTo200thMillisecond();
            Console.WriteLine($"value = {value:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}, rounded = {rounded:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}");
        }
    }
}

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime RoundTo200thMillisecond(this DateTime value)
    {
        long elapsed = (long)((value - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds);
        return DateTime.MinValue + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((elapsed + 100) / 200 * 200);
    }
}
```

ouput:

```
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:38.174, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:38.200
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:38.534, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:38.600
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:38.893, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:38.800
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:39.252, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:39.200
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:39.612, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:39.600
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:39.971, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:40.000
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:40.330, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:40.400
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:40.690, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:40.600
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:41.049, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:41.000
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:41.409, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:41.400
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:41.768, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:41.800
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:42.127, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:42.200
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:42.487, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:42.400
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:42.846, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:42.800
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:43.206, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:43.200
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:43.565, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:43.600
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:43.924, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:44.000
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:44.284, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:44.200
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:44.643, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:44.600
value = 2018-05-22 21:50:45.002, rounded = 2018-05-22 21:50:45.000
```

Comment: Good answer. Just liked titans above. Bit to many brackets for me :) You guys much smarter than I!